# test.vbs(21, 1) Microsoft Office Excel: Reference is not valid

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

Why do I get this error ? What am I missing ? I am trying to calculate the Goalseek using VBScript, many thanks !

```
Dim Excel
Dim xlBook
Dim xlSheet
Dim xyz

Set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = Excel.Workbooks.Add
Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)
   xlSheet.Application.Visible = 1

xlSheet.Application.Visible = True
xlSheet.Application.Cells(1, 1).Value = "This is column A, row 1"
xlSheet.Application.Cells(1, 2).Value = 200
xlSheet.Application.Cells(1, 3).Value = 0.1
xlSheet.Application.Cells(2, 2).Value = "=B1-190-C1"

Wscript.Echo "Like this?"
Wscript.Echo xlSheet.Application.Cells(1, 3)
Wscript.Echo xlSheet.Application.Range("B2")

xlSheet.Application.Range("B5").GoalSeek Goal=0, ChangingCell=xlSheet.Application.Range("B2")


xlSheet.SaveAs "C:\TEST.XLS"
xlSheet.Application.Quit
Set xlSheet = Nothing
```

Comment: `.GoalSeek Goal=0, ChangingCell=xlSheet.Application.Range("B2")` -> `.GoalSeek 0, xlSheet.Application.Range("B2")`

Comment: It is not working: xlSheet.Application.Range("B2").GoalSeek 0, xlSheet.Application.Range("B2") I guess there is a problem with not applying it to the right column or something ...

Comment: `B5` is the cell with your function, and `B2` is an empty cell? 0 is the desired target value for the function?